# Convert Microsoft JSON Date to Local DateTime Using Moment JS Only

Tags: javascript, json, date, datetime, momentjs

JSON Date: '/Date(1373428800000)/'
End Result: 7/9/2013 8:00 PM EST

Currently I do it in 3 steps:

```
var a = cleanJsonDate('JsonDate');
var b = formatDate(a); // 7/10/2013 12:00 AM
var c = moment.utc(b); // 7/9/2013 8:00 PM
return c;
```

Is it possible to accomplish the same result using moment js only?

----Update-----

Combining @ThisClark & @Matt answers. I came as close as possible to the goal; however, the 'h' format does not work for some reason, I still get 20.00.00 instead of 8:00

```js
var m = moment.utc(moment('/Date(1373428800000)/').format('M/D/YYYY h:m A')).toDate();
alert(m);
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 14):

This format is already [supported natively by moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/asp-net-json-date/). Just pass it directly.

```
moment('/Date(1373428800000)/')
```

You can then use any of the moment functions, such as `.format()` or `.toDate()`

If you want UTC, then do:

```
moment.utc('/Date(1373428800000)/')
```

Again, you can call `format` or `toDate`, however be aware that `toDate` will produce a `Date` object, which will still have local time behaviors.  Unless you absolutely need a `Date` object, then you should stick with `format` and other moment functions.

Comment: Updated to address your updated question.  The code you showed in your update is not recommended.  Sorry I didn't see this edit sooner.

Comment: Brilliant answer. I knew about moment parsing .NET dates, although I didn't know about .format, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I don't see all your code, but if you can just get the value of milliseconds as `1373428800000` out of that json, then you can pass it to moment directly. I think `formatDate` is a function you wrote. Does it do something important like manipulate time that you require of moment.js, or could you just use the format function of moment?

```js
var date = 1373428800000;
var m = moment.utc(date);
//var m = moment.utc(date).format('M/D/YYYY H:mm A'); <-- alternative format
alert(m);
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. But why is it returning July 10th instead of 9th. And yes formatDate is a custom method; however, I don't think moment needs it all.

Comment: Not sure why a and b are always invalid or NaN and d returning 12 AM
var date = item.StartDate.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
var a = moment.utc(date);
var b = moment.utc(date).format('M/D/YYYY H:mm A');
var c = 1373428800000;
var d = moment.utc(c).toDate();
var e = moment.utc(c).format('M/D/YYYY H:mm A');  
alert(a + " " + b + " " + d +  " " + e);    
// NaN Invalid date 7/10/2013 12:00 AM 7/10/2013 4:00 AM

Comment: What value is in `item.StartDate` before you modify it with a regular expression, and what is it you are trying to achieve with that regular expression?

Comment: With that regular expression I am extracting the numbers out of the json returned data value. I think I forgot to parse the extracted value into integer using parseInt(date)

Comment: 1373428800000 is 7/10/2013 12:00 AM (midnight) when converted that should result into 4 hours earlier 7/9/2013 8:00 PM. Not sure why we are getting 4 hours later 7/10/2013 4:00 AM. That does not make sense to me...

Comment: Try `var date = parseInt(item.StartDate);` then, do `var m = moment.utc(date).format(/*your format here*/);` Does it work for you?